# DataGridView hidden column doesn't stay hidden

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, hide

I have a DataGridView tied to a DataTable source.  Among the data on the elements in the table is a Guid which I want to remain hidden.  (It's used internally for reference, but should not be displayed.)  The code I'm using to create the table is as follows:

```
private DataTable mEntities = new DataTable();
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView EntitiesGridView;
```

These are declared elsewhere, just showing here for reference.

```
private void BuildEntityTable()
{
    mEntityTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Guid));
    mEntityTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    ...  (some other columns)

    foreach (Foo foo in mEntities)
    {
        DataRow row = mEntityTable.NewRow();
        row["id"] = foo.id;
        row["Name"] = foo.Name;
        ...  (rest of data)
        mEntityTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    DataColumn[] entityKeys = new DataColumn[1];
    entityKeys[0] = entityTable.Columns["id"];
    mEntityTable.PrimaryKey = entityKeys;

    EntitiesGridView.DataSource = mEntityTable.DefaultView;

    EntitiesGridView.Columns["id"].visible = false;
}
```

So far so good.  The table is created, and there's no visible "id" column.  However, if I later add a new object to the table, we run into trouble.  The code is almost the same:

```
void AddNewObject(object sender, MyArgs e)
{
    Foo foo = e.Foo;
    lock (mEntities)
    {
        mEntities.Add(foo);
    }
    lock (mEntityTable)
    {
        DataRow row = mEntityTable.NewRow();
        row["id"] = foo.id;
        row["Name"] = foo.Name;
        ...  (rest of data)
        mEntityTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

For some reason, this makes the "id" column come back.  I've tried copying the      `EntitiesGridView.Columns["id"].visible = false;` line from the previous code, but it does no good.  Nothing I do after this point will make that column go away and stay gone.  Any clues what I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you have both mEntities and mEntityTable? When I tried a datatable built like yours bound to a datagridview, adding a new row did not reproduce the issue - the hidden column stayed hidden. Maybe provide a minimal example that reproduces the error, in fact by doing that you might find the issue yourself. Also, where does AddNewObject get called from? I'm guess it is from other threads hence the locks? Doubt that would contribute to the issue but there seems to be a bit more going on than you have shown.

Comment: The DataTable is used to fill a PropertyGrid.  The DataGridView only shows a few key values from the DataTable, while the PropertyGrid shows them all.  (Dozens in some cases.)  There's more going on here that I didn't post since it might confuse things.  The "Foo" here is actually a custom class dynamically generated at runtime with fancy PropertyDescriptor stuff.  AddNewObject is called by an Xml Parser receiving the data over a network to create new objects on the fly.  I doubt any of this is related to the issue I'm having however, and it'd be way too much code if I posted it all.

Comment: Fair call, does sounds like the extra things wouldn't affect this. As I said, a simple example just adding to the datatable within a button event handler doesn't reproduce the issue. All I can think of that might affect it is the issue discussed in this forums thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/19841219-f1fc-454b-a019-097529a211e1/

Comment: Hmm.  Only thing I see in common with that case is that it is the first column giving me trouble.  Their GridView is pre-made at design time, while mine is created at run-time based on external data.  I put "id" and "Name" first, because those are the only two things guaranteed to be on every object.  Everything else is dynamic and unpredictable at design-time, so changing the order much isn't really an option.  (At best ID could be second, but the ID is used for data-syncing between the GUI and the source, and row identification, so it's most critical to have it in a predictable location.)

Answer (score 1):

just write this line

```
datagridview1.Columns[0].visible = false;
```

Comment: Look at my code - I did.  (Last line in the second block).  It goes away, but then comes back for no explicable reason.

Answer (score 0):

call this event in your form_load()

```
    private void dgv_DataBindingComplete(Object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        dgv.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it having been over a year since I asked this, I have no way of knowing if this would work - the project is long since finished, and if I recall, this part was completely refactored.  I don't even have access to the code anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem, but found that you can make your datagridview changes at design time and then save the project. Run the application, then quit from the application. The dgv on the design form has now automatically changed its display. Close the form and reopen it and you will see that the columns you originally included/excluded are returned. No additional code is required for this fix.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't in any way an answer for this question - the DGV is populated at runtime by necessity.  And the hidden column appears at runtime.  It's not visible when you start the application, but any change made to the object causes it to appear.  I can't expect the end-user to have access to the source code and forms designer, and it wouldn't help anyhow.  (Also, this project was finished a year and a half ago and I don't work there anymore.)